# How to get the values from inputs of dynamically opening modals in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a foreach loop in blade which generates dynamic modal for each row where I want to fetch the values of inputs from the open modal and edit the record through AJAX but cannot get the values. Please see the below code I am working on:

```
@foreach($doctors as $doctor)
    <tr class="tr">
        <td>{{ $doctor->id }}</td>
        <td>{{$doctor->name}}</td>
        <td>{{ $doctor->percentage }}</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-
        target="#editModal-{{ $doctor->id }}" id="btnEdit" value="{{$doctor->id }}">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" 
        data-target="#modal_theme_primary">Delete</button>
        </td>
        <td><!-- Horizontal form modal -->
        <div id="editModal-{{ $doctor->id }}" class="modal fade">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h5 class="modal-title">Edit Record</h5>
             </div>

              <form action="#" class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="form-group">
                   <label class="control-label col-sm-3"><b>Name:</b></label>
                   <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtName" 
                    value="{{ $doctor->name }}">
                   </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="control-label col-sm-3"><b>Percentage:</b></label>
                   <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtPercentage" 
                    value="{{ $doctor->percentage }}">
                   </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <button id="btnSaveChanges" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
                 </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /horizontal form modal -->
</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Now when I click the `Edit` button the modal for the clicked row opens up from where I want to get the values from the inputs of the open modal.
when I use the following code it alerts the first record's values.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(document).on('click', '#btnSaveChanges' function(){
            var id = $('#btnEdit').val();
            var name = $('#txtName').val();
            var percentage = ('#txtPercentage').val();
            alert(id + " " + name + " " + percentage);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use an id several times. Right now every time you make a new modal you add in the same id's (btnEdit, txtName, txtPercentage). You can not make the right selection when using duplicate id's with jQuery by selecting id.

In the example below I have used classes instead of id's to select the modal inputs.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('.btnSaveChanges').click(function() {
   var parent = $(this).parent().parent();

    var name = parent.find('.txtName').val();
    var percentage = parent.find('.txtPercentage').val();

    alert(name + " " + percentage);
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="editModal-1" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h5 class="modal-title">Edit Record</h5>
      </div>

      <form action="#" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3"><b>Name:</b></label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <input type="text" class="form-control txtName"value="name1">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3"><b>Percentage:</b></label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <input type="text" class="form-control txtPercentage" value="10%">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnSaveChanges">Save Changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="editModal-2" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h5 class="modal-title">Edit Record</h5>
      </div>

      <form action="#" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3"><b>Name:</b></label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <input type="text" class="form-control txtName"value="name2">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3"><b>Percentage:</b></label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <input type="text" class="form-control txtPercentage" value="20%">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnSaveChanges">Save Changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```